# strange behavior of powf() function

Tags: matlab, cuda, pow

In an unexpected manner,`powf` produces a strange output for odd base numbers when its type is `int`. For example `powf(-4,2)`returns `16` but `powf(-5,2)` returns`24` !!!

After tracing the root of a wrong output in a long calculation, I figured out that `powf` function shows strange behavior for odd numbers when output type is an `integer`.

```
__global__ void intFoo( int* a) 
{
    *a = powf(*a, 2);
}
__global__ void doubleFoo( double* a) 
{
    *a = powf(*a, 2);
}
```

I can call this kernel (for instance) in Matlab :

```
!nvcc -ptx test.cu 
k1 = parallel.gpu.CUDAKernel('test.ptx', 'test.cu', 'intFoo');
k2 = parallel.gpu.CUDAKernel('test.ptx', 'test.cu', 'doubleFoo');
out1 = feval(k1, -4)
out2 = feval(k1, -5)
out3 = feval(k2, -4)
out4 = feval(k2, -5)
```

result:

```
out1 = 16
out2 = 24 //This hasn't to be 25 !!??
out3 = 16
out4 = 25.000
```

**EDIT:**

After investigating in Matlab by @Robert Crovella suggestion, I found out that Command Window in Matlab shows `out4=25.000` as opposed to Variables Window which shows the content of `out4 = 24.9999981`.

Everyone should be very cautious as there is a small error associated with output of `powf` function (`24.9999981` instead of `25`) that may get propagated and become a problem with large calculations

Comment: first of all your variable sequence is out1, out2, out3, out4, but your output sequence shows out1, out1, out1, out1.  second, if the sequence is correct, you appear to be evaluating out1, out3 based on k1 and -4 **twice**, and  out2, out4 based on k2 and -5 **twice**.  It doesn't look like you are evaluating -5 with both `int` and `double`

Comment: @RobertCrovella Sorry , my mistake. Sequence is incorrect. I will edit my question.

Comment: your edit still shows `feval(k2, -5)` twice.  I don't see anywhere that you did `feval(k1, -5)`

Comment: @RobertCrovella sorry, now it has to be correct. since I'm running the code on a remote server and for some reason copying clipboard doesn't work... I wrote it here directly....

Comment: This is some issue associated with matlab, not just cuda.  I think you should at least tag this question with `matlab`.  Pure CUDA C++ doesn't show this type of behavior, so I think there is some variable mixup going to or from matlab environment.  I suspect what is happening is that the `powf` function on `(-5,2)` returns 24.999998 (that is what I see in CUDA C++), and when converted back to an integer (because [that is how matlab feval works](https://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/feval.html)) it is getting truncated to 24.  By comparison `powf(-4,2)` in CUDA C++ returns "exactly" 16.00000

Comment: Try using `pow` instead of `powf` and I suspect you'll see 25 instead of 24.

Comment: @RobertCrovella, Thanks for the suggestion and helpful reply. I will tag Matlab too. But any explanation for 24.999998 ?? because this number seems to be a strange output too!!

Comment: I believe I have covered most of this in my answer.  The 24.999998 is within the published error bounds (refer to my answer).  If you need further explanation, I suggest you ask a new question for that.  24.999998 is very close to the correct result of 25 and it is not reasonable or wise to expect perfect accuracy from floating point routines.

Comment: @RobertCrovella, yes, that was a comment before seeing your wonderful answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this is due to unwise usage of datatypes with `feval`.

It appears to me that [`feval`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/feval.html) converts the return type to be the same type as the parameter type.  This makes sense, since the return type is extracted from the pointer to the passed argument for that parameter.

note that `powf` takes `float` parameters and returns a `float`, and `pow` takes `double` parameters and returns a `double`.  `int` quantities don't have a separate function (prototype) in [the CUDA math API](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-math-api/group__CUDA__MATH__SINGLE.html#group__CUDA__MATH__SINGLE), so if you use them they will be cast to and from floating point types.

Here's what I see in pure CUDA C++:

```
$ cat t32.cu
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

__global__ void Foo( int a, double b)
{
            float res = powf((float)a, 2);
            printf("powf_int: %d, %d, %f\n", a, (int)res, res);
            res = powf((float)b, 2);
            printf("powf_double: %f, %f, %f\n", b, (double)res, res);
            double dres = pow((double)a, 2);
            printf("pow_int: %d, %d, %f\n", a, (int)dres, dres);
            dres = pow((double)b, 2);
            printf("pow_double: %f, %f, %f\n", b, (double)dres, dres);
}

int main(){

        Foo<<<1,1>>>(-5, -5);
        cudaDeviceSynchronize();
}
$ nvcc -o t32 t32.cu
$ cuda-memcheck ./t32
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
powf_int: -5, 24, 24.999998
powf_double: -5.000000, 24.999998, 24.999998
pow_int: -5, 25, 25.000000
pow_double: -5.000000, 25.000000, 25.000000
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
$
```

Note that:

1. CUDA `powf` returns 24.999998 for `(-5,2)`
2. if we convert this to `int` it gets truncated to 24
3. if we convert this to `double` and then round to 3 decimal places, the correctly rounded result would be 25.000 just as displayed in your matlab output

Suggestions:

1. don't do this
2. don't use integer types with floating point functions (especially casting the result)
3. if you want to square something, just multiply it with itself.  It will definitely be faster than using `powf(x, 2)` and will possibly be more accurate also.

If you want to know "why does CUDA `powf(-5, 2)` return 24.999998?", please ask that in a separate question.  The accuracy is defined in the [programming manual](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#intrinsic-functions__single-precision-floating-point-intrinsic-functions-supported-by-cuda-runtime-library) and I'm reasonably sure this falls within the published error bounds.  [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74661183/cuda-problem-with-counting-prime-numbers-from-1-n) is another example of `pow` "weirdness".

Comment: This answer seems comprehensive and completely explains the situation

Comment: So today's lesson is ,as you have mentioned, "don't use integer types with floating point functions". And as you suggested using multiplication instead of powf, I got an incredible speed up (almost 4x) in whole calculation.
It took me more than one day to figure out this silly mistake inside a huge complicated calculations. Hope I'm the last person in this planet falling in this trap...

Answer (score 2):

As an addendum to Robert Crovella's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54103594/780717): CUDA is a subset of C++ and therefore provides overloaded math functions. In particular it offers the following four variants of `pow()`:

```
float pow (float, int); 
double pow (double, int); 
float pow (float, float); 
double pow (double, double);
```

If you check the machine code generated for these variants with `cuobjdump --dump-sass` you will find that four different implementations are used. As Robert Crovella pointed out, for the particular case of squaring it is best to simply use multiplication, but you could certainly use `pow()` if you wanted to, as demonstrated by the following code (error checks omitted for conciseness):

```c++
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>

__global__ void kernel (int ib, float fa, float fb, double da, double db)
{
    printf ("pow_float_int     = %15.8e\n", pow (fa, ib));
    printf ("pow_float_float   = %15.8e\n", pow (fa, fb));
    printf ("pow_double_int    = %23.16e\n", pow (da, ib));
    printf ("pow_double_double = %23.16e\n", pow (da, db));
}

int main (void)
{
    int ia = -5, ib = 2;
    float fa = ia, fb = ib;
    double da = ia, db = ib;

    kernel<<<1,1>>>(ib, fa, fb, da, db);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The output of the above program should look something like this:

```
pow_float_int     =  2.50000000e+01
pow_float_float   =  2.49999981e+01
pow_double_int    =  2.5000000000000000e+01
pow_double_double =  2.5000000000000000e+01
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. yes, I confirm that `pow` do the job without any compromise. But for the people landing on this page : "use multiplication instead of `pow` or `powf` to gain a huge speed up in case of massive computation"