# CUDA - problem with counting prime numbers from 1-N

Tags: c++, cuda, nvidia

I just started with CUDA and wanted to write a simple C++ program using Visual Studio that can find total number of prime numbers from 1-N. I did this:

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"

#include <cstdio>
#include <cmath>

static void HandleError(cudaError_t err,
    const char* file,
    int line) {
    if (err != cudaSuccess) {
        printf("%s in %s at line %d\n", cudaGetErrorString(err),
            file, line);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}
#define HANDLE_ERROR( err ) (HandleError( err, __FILE__, __LINE__ ))

__global__ void countPrimeGPU(const int* array, int* count)
{
    int number = array[threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x];
    if (number <= 1)
        return;
    for (int i = 2; i <= floor(pow(number, 0.5)); i++)
        if (!(number % i)) 
            return;
    atomicAdd(count, 1);
}

int main()
{
    int* host_array; 
    int* dev_array;  
    const int size = 9; // prime numbers from 1-9

    // allocating & initializing host array
    host_array = new int[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) 
        host_array[i] = i + 1; // 1, 2, ..., size

    int host_primeCount = 0;
    int* dev_pprimeCount;

    HANDLE_ERROR(cudaSetDevice(0));
    HANDLE_ERROR(cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_array, size * sizeof(int)));
    HANDLE_ERROR(cudaMemcpy(dev_array, host_array, size * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
    HANDLE_ERROR(cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_pprimeCount, sizeof(int)));
    HANDLE_ERROR(cudaMemcpy(dev_pprimeCount, &host_primeCount, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
    countPrimeGPU <<< size, 1 >>> (dev_array, dev_pprimeCount); // !!!
    HANDLE_ERROR(cudaGetLastError());
    HANDLE_ERROR(cudaDeviceSynchronize());
    HANDLE_ERROR(cudaMemcpy(&host_primeCount, dev_pprimeCount, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
    printf("Prime count for the first %d numbers: %d\n", size, host_primeCount);

    cudaFree(dev_array);
    cudaFree(dev_pprimeCount);
    HANDLE_ERROR(cudaDeviceReset());
    delete[] host_array;
    return 0;
}
```

The problem here is that I get correct result only when `size` is in interval `[1-8]`. But, when setting it to `9` or above it is always incorrect. What am I doing wrong? I suspect I have incorrectly set the configuration (number of blocks/threads) when calling `countPrimeGPU`, but was unable to fix it. Ultimately, I would like to test it with `size=10'000'000`, and compare it with my multi-threaded CPU implementation. Thank you.

Comment: Do not tag C for C++ questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proximal issue is that when `number` is 9, `floor(pow(number, 0.5))` is giving you 2, not 3 as you expect. As a result, 9 is incorrectly flagged as a prime.

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54103146/strange-behavior-of-powf-function) is a similar question. `pow()` (at least, in CUDA device code) does not have the absolute accuracy you desire/need when using `floor()` (i.e. truncation). You might have a workable path using ordinary rounding rather than truncation (since testing against a factor slightly larger than the square root is not going to disrupt the correctness of your approach), but the method I would suggest to address this is to change your for-loop as follows:

```
for (int i = 2; (i*i) <= number; i++)
```

This avoids the floating-point head scratching, and should be computationally simpler as well.  For your desired range of `number` (up to 10,000,000) the quantity `i*i` will fit in a `int` type/value, so I don't forsee issues there.

Since this is just a learning exercise, I'm not trying to scrub your code for all sorts of optimization improvements.  To pick one example, launching blocks of 1 thread each:

```
countPrimeGPU <<< size, 1 >>> (dev_array, dev_pprimeCount); // !!!
```

is not particularly efficient on the GPU, but it is not algorithmically incorrect to do so.

Comment: Yes, I tried now using `size/500` blocks, `500` threads and got much better performance!

Comment: @Tracer Ideally use multiples of the warp size (32). I.e. 512 or even 1024, which is the maximum.

Comment: There is no programming language or use case I can think of where using exponentiation to compute a square root would be appropriate. Use `sqrt()` instead: (1) generally more accurate (2) generally faster (3) makes programmer's intent clearer.