# C++/CUDA equation printing incorrect answer

Tags: c++, cuda

currently I am trying to print out the answer to an equation using CUDA.

This equation is (x+y)^2 / xy

An example of the outputs I am getting are in this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/khp4H.png) attached.

```
__global__ void proof() {
    int x = 1;
    int y = 1;
    int multi_number = 1000;

    while (true) {
        long eq = ((pow(x + y, 2)) / (x * y));

        if (y >= multi_number) {
            if (x >= multi_number) {
                printf("\nProof is true for all cases.");
                break;
            }
        }

        if (x >= multi_number) {
            x = 1;
            y = y + 1;
        }

        printf("\nEquation being used: (%d", x);
        printf("+%d", y);
        printf(")^2 / %d", x);
        printf("*%d", y);
        printf(" >= 4");
        printf("\n%d", eq); // printing the equations answer

        if (eq < 4) {
            printf("\nProof Failed: %d", x);
            printf(", %d", y);
            break;
        }

        x = x + 1;
    }
}
```

I have currently tried rewriting the equation in multiple different ways, this did not work.

For the failed test (55+55)^2 / 55*55 I was expecting 4 to be printed instead of 3.

An example of a correct answer would be (1+1)^2 / 1*1 = 4

Comment: @RobertCrovella Hi there, I added in more of the code that i deleted because i thought it would clutter the post a bit more. The reason i believed the output would be 12100 is because thats what i got when i put in (55+55)^2 / (55*55) into a calculator [found out this was calculator error just now]. Y gets increased by 1 whenever X hits the "multi_number" number. I thought what I was printing out was the answer to the equation and not x or y. I guess thats another error on my behalf. Any helps is appreciated and sorry for wasting time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a nutshell, `pow()` (in CUDA device code, at least) does not have the accuracy you need/desire when using truncation.  I just answered a very similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74661183/cuda-problem-with-counting-prime-numbers-from-1-n/74661671#74661671).

The reason for the failure is that the result of `((pow(x + y, 2)) / (x * y))` (evaluated at the point (55,55)) is not 4 like you would expect, it is 3, when converted to a `long` value via truncation.

According to my testing, you can work around this by changing this line:

```
    long eq = ((pow(x + y, 2)) / (x * y));
```

to this:

```
    long eq = ((x+y)*(x+y)) / (x * y);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked perfectly. I'll keep this in mind in the future.

Answer (score -1):

Try this code

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <cuda_runtime.h>

   __global__ void calculate(float x, float y, float *result)
   {
*result = (x + y) * (x + y) / (x * y);
   }

 int main(void)
{
float x = 3.0, y = 2.0;
float result;

cudaMalloc((void **)&x, sizeof(float));
cudaMalloc((void **)&y, sizeof(float));
cudaMalloc((void **)&result, sizeof(float));

cudaMemcpy(x, &x, sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
cudaMemcpy(y, &y, sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

calculate<<<1,1>>>(x, y, result);

cudaMemcpy(&result, result, sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

cudaFree(x);
cudaFree(y);
cudaFree(result);

printf("The result of the calculation is %f\n", result);

return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).